# kubuntu 16.04: my panel icons keep disappearing after an upgrade

Tags: kde, kubuntu, plasma

Intel "Core-2" processor (refurbished), Dell box, 2GiB RAM. 
I had all the everyday applications placed on the bottom 'panel.'  Then I installed several new packages using Aptitude.  Afterward. about half of the icons on the panel had disappeared (or become invisible).  The launchers are still there, and work; only the display is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while I was on Kubuntu. It seems to be a bug with KDE and I have not been able to solve it. Interestingly enough the issue seems to be on Kubuntu but not on openSUSE with KDE and Plasma 5.

Still I recommend you visit [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) or the [Kubuntu Forums](http://www.kubuntuforums.net). It might also be worth, checking back with [KDE](http://forum.kde.org) itself.

Alternatively you can try adding the [Kubuntu Backports](https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/backports). This will download some updates for both Plasma and KDE, which might actually fix your issue.

Sincerely,

Ben

Answer (score 0):

If you have the problem described in this post on askubuntu.com:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/621222/after-installation-kubuntu-some-application-launcher-icon-missing

then I managed to get back most of the icons by setting again the icon theme as suggested in one of the comments [System Settings -> Icons]. Before installation I had some non-standard theme chosen and it got removed during the upgrade.